# MySQL 5.7 via brew on MacOS 12.6: how to get past "Access denied" barrier?

Tags: password, homebrew, monterey, mysql

I've been through every how-to I can find on the internet, but none are working for me. I've got a fresh install of MySQL 5.7 via homebrew. I can see that the service is running, and the `mysql` client is installed as well.

Any attempt to get to the database via the client, like

```
mysql -u root -p
```

or more simply

```
mysql -u root
```

as the installation process suggests, asks for a password with the prompt "Enter password:". Well, I just installed the database; I have no idea what the password is. Using `sudo` makes no difference. I've tried solutions involving `mysqladmin` with essentially the same result: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'".

I've got a bunch of experience with Postgresql, but it's got a significantly different way of dealing with mapping platform identity to db identity apparently. How do I get this thing to work?

(Note that the many answers in Ask Different are among the ones I've tried already with the exact same problem.)

Comment: I'm about to do a thing that drives me a little crazy on Stackoverflow, which is to leave my keyboard immediately after posting a question. My apologies, I will be back in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the bit where the security policy is setup. This requires defining the password validation policy and setting the root password, as well as connectivity options and managing a test database.

Install mysql.

Restart service: `brew services restart mysql`

Setup security: `mysql_secure_installation`

Login: `mysql -uroot -p`

Answer (score 0):

The formula told you what to do when you installed it.

From https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mysql@5.7

> We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure
> it run:
> mysql_secure_installation
>
> MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by
> default
>
> To connect run:
> mysql -u root

"Every how-to you can find on the internet", but not Homebrew's own documentation...

Comment: I type that, and the variation I see in my install message (`mysql -uroot`), no luck. "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'".